# FB Debuger: Image Unavailable Error while downloading https://myimage.jpg with HTTP response code: 404

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post link from my blog site to my facebook page. When I copy link and paste into facebook there is no image from that link only post content is here. When open debuger and paste that url then I get error like from title:

**Image Unavailable Error while downloading https://myimage.jpg with HTTP response code: 404**

Also want to mention that I already try using correct Thumbnail proportion for facebook image.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to share? And URLs should be absolute not relative

Comment: Representation of link that I trying to share is https://mywebsite.com/post_id/. In Open Graph properties where is og:image there is empty field but when I click on thath field then I been redirected to link where is my picture stored.

Comment: UPDATES ----

I created subdomain without using ssl certifacate and then try provide that URLs from that subdomains using http:// instead https:// to my facebook page and this approach work. Is this mean that fb have some issue with https:// URLs?

Comment: No Facebook has no problem with https as long as you set it up correctly. You can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ for example to figure out what you done wrong

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the image to a different folder on my server and that fixed the problem. Facebook somehow could not fetch the image from the previous folder. I dont know why. So try this, maybe it will work for you.